# Can Mathematica estimate this complex function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, series-expansion, asymptotics

Mathematica has given me a function in $x,r$ given by

```
fun[x_, r_] := 
   -Re[(E^(x/r)*r*x^2*((-(x/r))^x + 
     (r + (x*ExpIntegralE[x, -(x/r)])/E^(x/r))/
     (r*Gamma[1 - x]))*Gamma[-x])/
     ((ExpIntegralE[x, -(x/r)] - E^(x/r)*r*(-(x/r))^x* Gamma[-x])*
     (-x^2 + r^3*(-2 + x)*(-1 + x)*
   Sum[
  (x*(x^2*(-(x/r))^s*ExpIntegralE[-1 + x - s, -(x/r)]* Gamma[3 - x] + 
    2*E^(x/r)*r^2* Gamma[2 - x + s] - 
     3*E^(x/r)*r^2*x*Gamma[2 - x + s] + 
     E^(x/r)*r^2*x^2* Gamma[2 - x + s] + 
     2*r*x* ExpIntegralE[x, -(x/r)]* Gamma[2 - x + s] - 
     3*r*x^2* ExpIntegralE[x, -(x/r)]*Gamma[2 - x + s] + 
     r*x^3*ExpIntegralE[x, -(x/r)]* Gamma[2 - x + s]))/
                (E^(x/r)*(-(x/r))^s)/(r^4*(-2 + x)*
                 (-1 + x)*Gamma[3 - x]*(2 + s)), 
   {s, 0, -1 + x}]))]
```

I would like to show that for $r > 1$ this function converges to $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity. In particular I am interested in the case $r = 5$, and by simply trying a few values for this function the convergence becomes clear. The function seems too complex for me to try anything by hand, but I would like Mathematica to provide me in some way with this limit. I have naturally attempted

```
Limit[fun[x, 5], x -> Infinity]
```

but this just yields the function again with a limit symbol before it. Similarly I have attempted to use

```
AsymptoticSolve[y == bound[x, 5], y, {x, Infinity, 2}]
```

but again Mathematica just gives up and provides me with my own request. Is there any trick, technique, etc. I could use to find some sort of limit, series, etc.?

Comment: Copy the code from the notebook cell by click right the bracket and copy as plain text. At first sight , there is a  sum[ ... , { K[2] = 0,   x-1} ). For a sum,  x has to be positive integer or the Floor of x , but where did you get  the Gamma[ K[2] -x ] on the negative integers.

Comment: Thank you @RolandF . I changed it to be plain text instead of input text. The origin of this function is that it is the solution of a recurrence divided by the solution of another recurrence. I will probably try to ask on the Mathematics Exchange if they can help me with these recurrences, but I think it is more promising to try and get Mathematica to provide information on the function in my original post. Also, x are indeed positive integers, but Mathematics seem to be able to calculate this function for any positieve real value of x except integers, funnily enough

Comment: If you try to get a value of your function, say f[3,5] it does not return a number (the answer is indeterminate).

Comment: `fun[3.0\`25 - 10^-15, 5]//FullForm` evaluates to `-0.169278996865202115\`7.8366521444527875`

Answer (score 1):

in the Sum in the expression, clearly, is a sum over Gamma of negative reals. Gamma has poles at all non-positive integers

[image: Gamma function]

So the sum makes no sense for x an integer, without a presciption, what to do with the poles.

If the  upper limit of sum x is a non-integer, the sum is running with index s integer but, with Gamma[-x] between the poles, a possible way to describe a discontinuity.

According to my gutt instinct, the free floating x in the Gammas makes no sense, as it not related to the integer upper limit of the sum up to Floor[x].

Plot[ fun[7.5, r], {r, 2, 17}]

[image: Trial plot of fun]

Since the Gamma[-x] converge exponentially  fast to zero between the poles, its a fact, the the fun sum converges in all open intervalls between the integers to zero with length -> oo , but of course not uniformly so.

```
ListPlot[Log[Abs[Gamma[Range[-22.5, 4.5]]]]]
```

[image: Log abs gamma]

Comment: Thank you for the answer (I sadly don't have the rep to mark it as useful). You naturally are right that the sum and convergence as it is right now makes little sense to the problems when x is an integer.

You are saying that the Gamma[-x] converge exponentially to zero between the poles, but we also divide over a lot of functions with Gamma and ExpIntegral in it. How did you conclude that "the fun sum converges in all open intervals between the integers to zero with length ->  oo ". Is there some easy way to identify this behaviour, or did you just conclude it from the graphs?

Comment: Because the convergence to 0 in the open intervals is already enough information to me. I am just wondering how I can conclude that given the function looks so difficult to deal with

Comment: Also @RolandF are you sure that in this case changing the summation index to s does not make a difference? Because the code with the K was purely what Mathematica provided as the solution of a recurrence and not my own work, is the function that is in my question now equivalent? In any case, thank you for the elaborate help so far

Comment: The mathematica generated K[1].. are dummy interger sumations indices. Their names does not play a role, they just run through the given range. The convergent form for th exponentials and Ei for x negative is evident.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I indeed see they are equal now, I misinterpreted K. Sorry for asking so many questions, but what do you mean by 'the convergent form is evident'? I still don't see why I can conclude that the function f converges to 0 for large x (and, say, r=5) / how I can see which term dominates the function. I have some idea of the behaviour of Gamma and the ExpIntegral, but I see a lot of Gamma and ExpInt in both nominator and dominator and I still find it hard to make sense of this. I am probably missing something obvious